# Play! framework pass querystring

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

What is the correct Play! way to tack on a query string such as ?a=x&b=y to a render template call such as this:

```
render("@Login.index");
```

Also, I'd also like to maintain this query string through the subsequent form post as well (the following code snippet's crude attempt does not compile):

```
#{form @Login.login() + request.querystring, method:'post'}
```

I could probably work out some kludgey solution passing the original querystring explicitly as a parameter and then storing it perhaps in a hidden form field, but knowing Play! I'm sure there's something more elegant... could someone tell me what it is?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I think you need to change the way to code your form...

Just try:

```
%{
    action = play.mvc.Router.reverse("Login.login");
    for (String key : params.all() ) {
        if (!"body".equals(key) && !"controller".equals(key) && !"action".equals(key)) {
            action = action.add(key, params.get(key)[0]);
        }
    }
}%
#{form action, method:'post'}
    ...
#{/form}
```

Answer (score 0):

Play! is stateless, so you either have to repass the params:

```
#{a @login().add('a', _caller.params.a).add('b', _caller.params.b)}login#{/a}
```

Or keep the params inside Play's Cache:

```
Cache.set(session.getId(), params.get("a"), "5mn");
```